# Why increasing the expiry of keys would reclaim expired keys memory faster in Redis?

Tags: database, redis, nosql

Per [Reclaim expired keys memory faster](https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/memory-optimizations/#reclaim-expired-keys-memory-faster),

> You can follow one of these three steps to reclaim the memory:

> - Restart your redis-server
> - Increase memorysamples in redis conf. (default is 5, max is 10) so that expired keys are reclaimed faster.
> - You can set up a cron job that runs the scan command after an interval which helps in reclaiming the memory of the expired keys.
> - Alternatively, Increasing the expiry of keys also helps.

As we know, Redis uses a [randomized algorithm](https://redis.io/commands/expire/#how-redis-expires-keys) to find out keys that should be expired, so the second method would increase the probability of expired keys being reclaimed.

The third method the `scan` method could force a passive removal across all the keyspace

I am confused why the fourth method `Increasing the expiry of keys` could reclaim expired keys faster? Could someone give me more details?

Comment: That does sound confusing. Perhaps what they mean is not increasing the *expiry time*, but increasing the *expiry frequency* (by reducing the expiry time)? That is, increasing expiry means more expiry. Just a guess...